# Android task and back-stack issue

Tags: android

I have 3 activities: A, B and C.

A -> B -> C -> B (means A launches B, B launches C and so on)

B is singleTask, C is standard

Is possible to let C shown when user press BACK button in 4th activity (that is, the last activity, B)?

Comment: if you have gone through http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html and saying that why C is shown why not A then only GOD can do this miracle.not Android...:D  But we can reach to Activity A by removing activities from back stack

Comment: Please rephrase the last line of your question

Comment: from which activity back you want to show activity C ?

Answer (score 1):

Change Task B from singleTask back to standard.  You are not using singleTask correctly.  singleTask launch mode is meant to be used for activities that are at the root of a task.

You can only have one instance of a singleTask activity on your device.  When you "launch" B from C, you are just returning to the already existing instance of B.  So there is no fourth activity.

More Info at [Android Activity - Launch Mode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode)

Answer (score 0):

I think use can use 
moveTasktoBack(); in Activity class